# how to delete firebase Firstore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried several methods, but when I actually click the delete button, not just one document is deleted, but all the documents. What should I do? Here's the code:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
  db.collection('data').get().then((snapshot)=>{
    snapshot.forEach((doc)=>{

      const da = doc.id;

      function delei(){
        db.collection('data').doc(da).delete().then(()=>{
          console.log('deleted');
        })
      }

      


      var 템플릿 = `<div class="attend">
        <div class="date">${doc.data().날짜}</div>
        <div class="icons">
            <span class="download 48dp material-icons-outlined" onclick="location.href='${doc.data().엑셀}'">file_download</span>
            <span class="trash 48dp material-icons-outlined" onclick="${delei()}" >delete</span>
        </div>
    </div>`
      $('.big').append(템플릿);
    })
});
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing great.
I will share with you two links to a beautiful tutorial about your question from YouTube.
For firebase v9:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1frrNxq4js
For earlier version (like yours):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZqXcoqC95E&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9itfjle0ji1xOZ2cjRGY_WB&index=5
I'm sorry that I didn't write the code but I saw your question and I was so tired, and I wanted to help with anything useful.